# How to create a chart with multiple ranges in google apps script for google spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google apps script which deploys a variable number of sheets in the spreadsheet it is attached to, with the intent to gather data from an API, which is working just fine.

However, I want to visualize this data in graphs, and since it's meant to be self-deplorable, and because there are a variable number of these sheets of data, I want to create a number of charts representing various parts of the data, and in these charts have a range (series, or y axis), for every sheet of data, so it's variable depending on the initialization or setup.

Long story short and to make it less confusing, I simply want to know how to create a chart and add ranges for every chart. I could iterate through a list for example, but the problem is that I'm getting errors such as: 
"TypeError: Cannot find function modify in object EmbeddedChartBuilder. (line 97, file "Code")
Dismiss"

Also, note I'm trying to pull data from other sheets, so I'm using the sheetName!range notation.

Here's the particular function I'm working on, note I'm using placeholder values just to get something working for now.

```
// TODO
function createCharts(){
  var sheet = getSheet('Graphs');
  var winrateChart = sheet.newChart().setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE).setPosition(2, 1, 0, 0);
  // for every user, add appropriate range to chart 
  winrateChart = winrateChart.modify().addRange('username1!A1:B2');
  winrateChart = winrateChart.modify().addRange('username2!A1:B2');
  sheet.updateChart(winrateChart);
  winrateChart = winrateChart.build()
  sheet.insertChart(winrateChart);
}
```

Comment: instead of using multiple lines, why don't you do `winrateChart = winrateChart.modify().addRange('username1!A1:B2').addRange('username2!A1:B2').build();` and then update the sheet with it?

Comment: That won't work because I need to set up a loop which will iterate through sheet names, so I can pull data from every sheet. 
Like I said there's a variable number of sheets.
In pseudocode would be something like.

    for every sheet in sheetList
        add sheet's data to chart

Comment: What line of the code you showed us is `line 97`?

Comment: winrateChart = winrateChart.modify().addRange('username1!A1:B2');

I found the problem (partially, still didn't find a full solution, I took a break  because I've been coding all day), the EmbeddedChart class contains the method modify, however the EmbeddedChartBuilder class does not, I'm starting to figure out what the mechanism here is, the EmbeddedChartBuilder looks like it's used to modify charts and do other things, and it seems like the method build makes it into the other class, which is the object used to display the chart itself.

Comment: EmbeddedChart's modify()

Returns an EmbeddedChartBuilder that can be used to modify this chart. Invoke sheet.updateChart(chart) to save any changes. 

EmbeddedChartBuilder's build()

Return

EmbeddedChart — the created chart, which must still be added to the spreadsheet

The documentation is a little bit confusing in my opinion, but I'm starting to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out what the problems were, mostly through experimentation, I still am of the opinion the documentation is lacking clarity and good examples.
But here is my my understanding.

First of, there are three classes to deal with for this problem, Sheet, EmbeddedChart and EmbeddedChartBuilder.

EmbeddedChartBuilder is what is returned by Sheet.newChart(), by using the .build() method you get an EmbeddedChart class, which can be used as a parameter to Sheet.insertChart(). 
Furthermore through experimentation it seems like you must insert a chart by Sheet.insertChart(EmbeddedChart) before you can use EmbeddedChart.modify(), which in turn returns an EmbeddedChartBuilder, which you can use to chain any number of methods such as add range. And of course you still have to use .build() to return an EmbeddedChart from an EmbeddedChartBuilder, then Sheet.updateChart(EmbeddedChart) afterwards.

The last problem was a mistake I've made, I was calling .addRange() using a string as parameter, however addRange requires a Range object.

Anyway, here is some code demonstrating an example use, you can chain as many modify() as you want, for example in a loop that iterates through sheets.

Note: getSheet is a custom function, does what you'd expect.

```
function createCharts(){
  var sheet = getSheet('Graphs');
  var chart = sheet.newChart().setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE).setPosition(2,1,0,0).build(); // build returns an EmbeddedChart object 
  Logger.log(chart);
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
  chart = chart.modify().addRange(getSheet('someSheetName').getRange('B1:B999')).build();
  Logger.log(chart);
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
}
```

EDIT: here's the entire, working function, not useful outside this particular code, however, you can see the logic behind it, I'm gonna try to make it universally useful by iterating through sheets or something.

```
function createChart(range, x, y, title, width, height){
  // range: string; x: int; y: int; title: string; width: int; height; int
  // Creates a chart with data from all usernames for a given range at x row, y column, with a title, a width and height
  var sheet = getSheet('Graphs');
  // chart setup
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
  .setPosition(x,y,0,0)
  .setNumHeaders(1)
  .setOption('title', title)
  .setOption('width', width)
  .setOption('height', height)
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
  // for every username, add corresponding data into chart
  for(var i = 0; i < fortniteUsernames.length; i++){
    var username = fortniteUsernames[i];
    chart = chart.modify().addRange(getSheet(username).getRange(range)).build();
    sheet.updateChart(chart);    
  }
}
```

Comment: **2023**: This analysis is valuable. May I suggest a correction? `it seems that you must insert a chart by Sheet.insertChart(EmbeddedChart) before you can use EmbeddedChart.modify()`. This is not correct. By experimentation, I found that a chart inserted manually is an `Embedded Chart`; one _can_ use `chart.modify`. Refer [How to add a data series into a line chart in google sheets using Apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77209417/1330560) for an example. FWIW, `getSheets` didn't help this user to understand which `sheet` references were required. I think I simplified this.