# How to add a data series into a line chart in google sheets using Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I am trying to make a code that adds a new data series to a multi-series line chart in Google Sheets.
My data is (as usual) in columns and I want to be able to run a script that inserts a new column and then edit the chart so that the new data is displayed as a different data series, but I am stuck with editing the chart.

I am able to add a range using `chart.modify.addrange()`. This allows me to add the column with the new series to the chart range, but the chart won't show it as a new series unless I go into the chart editor and add new series manually. The range is already there, so it's not much work, but I'd like it to be fully automatic.
Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Edit:
I found out, where exactly lies the problem, but don't know, how to fix it. I will try to show the problem more clearly.

[My sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thnF9.png)

If I select data from first three columns, add chart and then run the following code, it will add data from the fourth column to the chart.

The script:

```js
function myFunction() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];

chart = chart.modify()
    .addRange(sheet.getRange("D1:D6"))
    .build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
}
```

[chart before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZwwK.png)
[chart after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KT9xQ.png)

However, the problem appears when I change the chart settings for the range of x-axis. When I insert the chart, set the x-axis to be the series "b" and then change it back to "a" and then run the script, series "d" doesn't appear. Upon closer inspection, I can see, that the range was added to the chart, but it didn't create a new data series out of it.

[The chart after script but edited before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1RrG.png)

You can see here, that the range in fact does contain D1:D6, but to display it as a data series, I have to add it manually.

Now why is this a problem. I want to edit in this way a chart, which I cannot create without changing axis settings. The data looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7SCq.png)

Number of rows of my data will increase rapidly, so I have to select whole columns to account for this. And, as you can see, I don't want the second column in the chart. But when i create the chart, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5kKb.png)

In order to make it look the way I want, I have to change the setting which somehow disrupts the code to work properly. When I make from this my line chart with correct x axis and series, The code behaves like in the example before and doesn't add new data as a new series.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide your current script, the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Show your full code. Are you calling `.updateChart()` at the end?

Comment: Related question: [Why can't I add a new series via Google Sheets App Scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74450991/1330560)

Comment: Related question: [TypeError: sheet.newChart(...).setChartType(...).setDataViewDefinition is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63246960/1330560)

Answer (score 0):

You have manually created a line chart in Google Sheets. You have added an extra range using app script but the chart does not reflect the new range.

My (working) code is shown below. At face value they are essentially identical BUT the issues to resolve are:

- is the displayed chart = `getCharts()[0]`?
- are there multiple, not-visible "Embedded Charts" on the sheet?

I found, though experimentation, that if a chart is **manually deleted** (i.e. highlight with the mouse and press "Delete"), the chart remains on the list of "Embedded Charts". In fact, one may manually create and delete many charts, leave no visible trace on screen **BUT** find that *all* the manually deleted charts are listed as "Embedded Charts".

So, if the chart displayed on screen isn't `getCharts()[0]` then any script is doomed to failure.

Included in this answer are two utilities:

- `listChartsOnSheet`: list all the Embedded Charts on the relevant sheet
- `deleteChartsFromSheet`: delete all the Embedded Charts from the relevant sheet

I suggest that the OP should:

1. run `listChartsOnSheet`. If there is more than one chart on the sheet,
2. run `deleteChartsFromSheet` to delete all the charts,
3. build a new chart (manually or by script)
4. run the `modify` script

---

```
function modifyChart() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetName = "chart"
  var chartSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)

  // define the additional range
  var range = chartSheet.getRange("D1:D6")

  // get the chart and make changes
  var chart = chartSheet.getCharts()[0];
  chart = chart.modify()
    .addRange(range)
    .setOption('title', 'Updated!')
    .build();
  chartSheet.updateChart(chart);
  
  Logger.log("updated chart")
}
```

---

**RESULTS: modify by apps script**

[image: modify]

---

**Chart: build - manual**

[image: manual build]

---

**Utility scripts**

**Build a chart**

```
function buildChart() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetName = "chart"
  var chartSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)
  
  // build the sheet
  var range = chartSheet.getRange("A1:C6")
  var chartBuilder = chartSheet.newChart();
  chartBuilder.addRange(range)
      .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
      .setPosition(20,8,0,0)
      .setOption('title', 'Version 1');
  chartSheet.insertChart(chartBuilder.build());

  Logger.log("new chart built")
}
```

---

**List the charts on sheet**

```
function listChartsOnSheet(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetName = "chart"
  var chartSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)

  // get the charts on this sheet
  var charts = chartSheet.getCharts();

  // loop through the charts
  for (var i in charts) {
    var chart = charts[i];
    Logger.log("chart#"+i+", ID is "+chart.getChartId())
  }
}
```

**Delete the charts on a sheet**

```
function deleteChartsFromSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetName = "chart"
  var chartSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)
  
  // loop through charts on this sheet and delete
  var charts = chartSheet.getCharts();
  for(let i = 0; i < charts.length; i++){
    chartSheet.removeChart(charts[i]);
  }
  Logger.log("removed all sheets")
}
```

---